# Adding dependencies into deps.edn in Spacemacs

Tags: clojure, spacemacs, edn

I’m trying to add dependencies to deps.edn typing `SPC r a p`. When I select a dependency, I get the following message: `cljr--insert-into-leiningen-dependencies: Search failed: ":dependencies"`. So apparently clj-refactor doesn’t recognize my deps.edn file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting pom.xml from project root solved the problem. I guess the problem was in
`cljr--project-file` function of clj-refactor.el file or some other function that consumes that one. `cljr--project-file` looks over possible project files and pom.xml precedes deps.edn.